# python while loop keeps on repeating

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, repeat

My problem is that when you answer a question the while loop keeps on repeating until all 10 questions are answered BUT this is only true for getting the answer correct
For getting it wrong it loops on forever

correct answer:

```
what is
 7  *  2

Answer here: 14
you got the answer right,well done
you got the answer right,well done
you got the answer right,well done
you got the answer right,well done
you got the answer right,well done
you got the answer right,well done
you got the answer right,well done
you got the answer right,well done
you got the answer right,well done
you got the answer right,well done
Welldone you have answered all 10 questions and managed to get correct: 10
press enter to exit
```

Wrong answer:

```
wrong
wrong
wrong
```

and this repeats on and on and it doesn't end

This is the code for the program

```
import random


correct,number,left,right = 0,0,random.randint(6,10),random.randint(1,5)

add =(left+right)
sub =(left-right)
mul =(left*right)

StrAdd =("+")
StrSub =("-")
StrMul =("*")
StrOp=StrAdd,StrSub,StrMul
StrRandOp=random.choice(StrOp)
print("\n\nwhat is\n",left,"",StrRandOp,"",right,)

given = float(input("\nAnswer here: "))
while number < 10:
    if given == add:
        print("you got the answer right,well done")
        correct=correct+1
        number=number+1
    elif given == sub:
        print("you got the answer right,well done")
        correct=correct+1
        number=number+1
    elif given == mul:
        print("you got the answer right,well done")
        correct=correct+1
        number=number+1
    else:
         print("wrong")
print("""Welldone you have answered all 10 questions and managed to get
correct:""", correct)
input("press enter to exit")
```

Comment: What *should* happen if a wrong answer is given?

Comment: You are missing `number=number+1` in the case of a wrong answer.

Comment: @Marein or a `break`, depending on what he wants to happen.

Comment: You could start by noticing that you probably want to increment number at end of your loop instead of at the end of each if/elseif/else block. Your last else block is missing an increment, resulting in the infinite loop. Finally, you only ask for user-input once, before your loop. It's very likely that this is undesired behavior if you wish to ask 10 questions.

Comment: @LukasGraf Although the final `print` suggests the former, I think.

Comment: @Marein fair point - keeping track of the number of correct answers also suggests that.

Comment: The real problem seems to be that you have put the `while` loop in the wrong spot. The variables `given`, `add`, `sub`, and `mul` have the same value at the end of every while loop as they have at the beginning.

Comment: so what would be the best spot to put them?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want:

```py
import random


correct,number,left,right = 0,0,random.randint(6,10),random.randint(1,5)

add =(left+right)
sub =(left-right)
mul =(left*right)

StrAdd =("+")
StrSub =("-")
StrMul =("*")
StrOp=StrAdd,StrSub,StrMul
StrRandOp=random.choice(StrOp)
print("\n\nwhat is\n",left,"",StrRandOp,"",right,)

given = float(input("\nAnswer here: "))
while number < 10:
    if given == add:
        print("you got the answer right,well done")
        correct=correct+1
    elif given == sub:
        print("you got the answer right,well done")
        correct=correct+1
    elif given == mul:
        print("you got the answer right,well done")
        correct=correct+1
    else:
         print("wrong")
    number = number + 1 
print("""Welldone you have answered all 10 questions and managed to get
correct:""", correct)
    input("press enter to exit")
```

When you want to iterate for a specific number of times it's better to use the `for` loop:

```
for number in range(0,10,1):
    print "sth"
```